# Пунктуация в сложных предложениях с перечислением

Tags: пунктуация, перечисление

Прошу помочь с пунктуацией в предложении такого формата:

*Дети-призраки, исчезнувшие с улиц городов, дети-марионетки, потерявшие чувство реальности в виртуальном мире, грязные, серые дороги разбитых горем селений — все наводило на меня тоску.*

Comment: Franky, да, я прочитал ответ Грамоты.ру. Пример, который я привел в коментарии, тоже взят изакадемиеского справочника. Там про обобщающие слова, действительно, ничего не говорится. Но, к сожалению, найти примеры, где точка с запятой стоит в предложениях, после обобщающего слова, мне не удалось.

Answer (score 1):

*Дети-призраки, исчезнувшие с улиц городов, дети-марионетки, потерявшие чувство реальности в виртуальном мире, грязные, серые дороги разбитых горем селений — всё наводило на меня тоску.*

Необходимо набрать тире (раз уж боремся за правильность в пунктуации), которое всегда можно найти в Таблице символов для любого шрифта ПК, а также Ё для однозначного распознавания слова, следующего после перечисления «Дети-призраки, дети-марионетки, серые дороги», где всё во мн. числе.

Comment: Спасибо, я в курсе про разницу между тире и дефисом. 
Больше интересовали знаки в перечислении. 

Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере ошибок нет.

Однородные члены предложения отделяются посредством запятой, тире ставится перед обобщающим словом.

Вот правило.

Обобщающее слово, стоящее после однородных членов, отделяется от них знаком тире: Поручни, компасы, бинокли, всякие приборы и даже высокие пороги кают **— всё это было медное** (Пауст.); И эти поездки, и наши с ней разговоры **— всё проникнуто было щемящей, безысходной тоской** (Бек.)

[§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)

Comment: Спасибо. А если перечисления будут еще больше распространены? Если их будет несколько? Кроме запятых ничего не нужно?

Comment: Нет, однородные члены предложения выделяются запятыми. Однако однородные члены предложения могут выделяется тире, если стоят в середине предложения и имеют характер уточнения.Подробнее см. в ссылке в ответе.

Comment: А как же вот это?
"11. Если стоящие после обобщающего слова однородные члены предложения сильно распространены и особенно если внутри них имеются запятые, то они разделяются точкой с запятой [ср. § 9, п. 3]: Земля, оказывается, бесконечно в е л и к а: и моря, и снеговые горы в облаках, и безбрежные пески; и неожиданные города с церквами, похожими на надетые друг на друга колокола; с деревьями, как высокие папоротники; и люди, чёрные, как вымазанные сажей, голые, страшные, как черти, и плосколицые, с крошечными глазками, в балахонах, в шлыках, с длинными косами;..."

Comment: Да, но обратите внимание: ваш пример не подходит под пункт этого правила.

Comment: То есть на постановку точки с запятой влияет исключительно структура предложения? Если очень распространенные однородные члены не стоят после обобщающего слова, то можно создать текст с одними лишь запятыми, а если стоят, нужны точки с запятой? Я правильно уловил суть?

Comment: Да. Но не обязательно, чтобы было обоб-е слово.Обычно они имеют зависимые слова или относящиеся к ним придаточные части предложений.

Comment: ***Его уважали за его отличные, аристократические манеры, за слухи о его победах; за то, что он прекрасно одевался и всегда останавливался в лучшем номере лучшей гостиницы; за то, что он вообще хорошо обедал, а однажды даже пообедал с Веллингтоном у Людовика-Филиппа; за то, что он всюду возил с собой настоящий серебряный несессер и походную ванну; за то, что от него пахло какими-то необыкновенными, удивительно «благородными» духами; за то, что он мастерски играл в вист и всегда проигрывал... (Т.)***

Answer (score 0):

В академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина пункт о постановке двоеточия между однородными членами предложения уже выведен из раздела об однородных членах с обобщающими словами.

В этом справочнике сказано:
Между однородными членами предложения (или их группами) может ставиться точка с запятой:
1) если в их состав включаются вводные слова;
2) если однородные члены распространены (имеют зависимые слова или относящиеся к ним придаточные части предложений).

Таким образом, мы делаем вывод, что при данных условиях точка с запятой может использоваться в том числе и в предложениях, где обобщающее слово стоит после однородных членов.